# Windows Phone Store App version upgrade with same reserved app name

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-8, versioning, windows-phone-store

I have public windows phone app with version 1.0 for windows 8
  - Now I have to do version upgrade to version 2.0 for the same app and users should get notifications for the same.
 - Should I use the same reserved app name as version 1.0 or use another app name for version 2.0
 - What will happen if I submit app with version 2.0 and the same app name?
 - Do I have to use another app name for next version? Or same app name will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to do anything with the `App Name Reservation`. The app name should be the same irrespective of the versions/update.

Your existing users will get notified via `Updates` only when you update your existing app. And if you reserve a new name(for your version 2) and publish it, it will be published as a new individual app and so your app will not be listed in the `Updates List` of your existing app users.

Comment: Hi Pradeep, I used the same App Name Reservation. Uploaded the new xap with version 2.0(previous version 1.0) for same windows platform(wp8). I selected "Add New" package and uploaded new xap but it replaced the verison 1.0 xap. Is this the how windows Dev Centre works? means replacing the older xap?

Comment: Hi, AddNewXAP feature should be used when you are submitting for a new version of OS . For example, if you want your 7.1 users to obtain a specific app, then you can upload a package for 7.1 and a package for 8.0, so that 7.1  people will get that 7.1build and the remaining people will get 8.0Build. More Info here http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/05/10/latest-windows-phone-app-submission-improvements/

Comment: Means, we have to replace it while upgrading version for same Windows phone OS. I did "Add new" for same WP OS but it automatically replaced the version 1.0 xap with version 2.0 xap. Is it something like Windows Dev Centre has taken care about this?

Comment: One more thing Pradeep, whatever link you have shared above shows Replace option in Upload and describe your package but I was not able to see replace option while uploading. It was only showing Delete option. Why?

Comment: Can you recheck that with your IE ?

Comment: Good. Are you using firefox earlier ?

Comment: Yes Pradeep, I was using firefox earlier.